# SignalR - How to get "ConnectionId" using - "IUserIdProvider"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

There is a possibility to map the `ConnectionId` when I'm using `IUserIdProvider`?

This variable `Clients.User(userIdTo)` is the type "`UserProxy`"

[image]

Any idea how I can get the ConnectionID circled in red?

Hugs

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate, I already read all about it earlier and not have what I need. So I created this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Context` property of the hub to get the `ConnectionId` property. That is: `Context.ConnectionId`

Comment: Thanks for the reply buddy, that's not what I'm talking about. I need ConnectioId user to whom I am sending the message, not "my" ConnectioId.

Comment: The connection ID you're asking for isn't accessible then. The connection ID you highlighted in your question is the connection ID of the caller to SendPrivate which has the same value as `Context.ConnectionId`.